# IDA: Meaning of Segment Register and it's length

Tags: assembly, intel, ida

I've looked everywhere on the Hex-Rays IDA documentation and couldn't find anything explaining this.

I am new to assembly code and am looking at a piece of fake malware for practice. **I am trying to understand how I can determine the address/location which holds an instruction**, so I can set a breakpoint and debug further. Below is a screenshot of a line in IDA that calls a function "unpack", with the "Segment Registers" window. I have 2 questions:

1. **Is the number under "Start" in the Segment Registers window the address in hex where the "unpack" function begins, and the "End" number the address where it ends?**
2. **What does each hex value represent? Is 080485A0 (the "Start" value in the Segment Registers window for the "unpack" function) the first instruction of the "unpack" function, with 080485A1 being the next instruction and so on?**

Or do I have this all wrong, and there's another way to determine the address/location of an instruction?

[image]

Comment: No, those are "segment register change points" as the caption says. Unrelated to where your functions are in memory. As the manual says, _"You can toggle between the text and graph view using the Space key. "_ Then you should see the addresses. Also note that the current address is printed in the status bar: _"0804865D main+9"_

Comment: If you want the `unpack` function, select it from the list on the left.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks! One more quick question i have is how comparisions work. I have as statement `cmp     [ebp+argc], 1` and then a jle statement right after. Does that mean "if ebp+argc is less than or equal to 1, jump to the specified address in the jle statement?"

Comment: If the content of memory at that address, yes. If you are confused about how an instruction works, consult the instruction set reference.

Comment: It is recommended to ask questions about Reverse Engineering in [Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com).